# Como visualizar dados de um banco de dados Cordova?

Tags: jquery, android, ios, apache-cordova

Gostaria de saber se existe um meio de acessar e visualizar dados gravados de um banco de dados [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage)?

Tenho uma aplicação *mobile* (Android e iOS) e sei que posso visualizar os registros usando `log` ou `alert` mas, existe alguma forma de visualizar estes dados no aparelho seja por um aplicativo ou outro meio?
Aplicativos Android nativos usavam o SQLite Database Browser mas não funciona com o Cordova.

Obrigado pela resposta e desculpe a demora! Tentei adicionar o ip, hostname e não é concluído o processo de adicionar o pc no smartphone. Apresenta erro informando que não foi localizado. Ao tentar deixar o smartphone localizar algum pc em rede, também não localiza.

Answer (score 2):

1. No seu Desktop instale no Navegador chrome a extensão [Adobe Edge Inspect CC](http://html.adobe.com/edge/inspect/).
2. No seu Dispositivo Movel instale o App "Edge Inspect"
3. Coloque os dois na mesma rede Wifi.
4. No seu Dispositivo Movel crie uma Connection informando o IP do seu Desktop.

Seu dispositivo móvel agora conversa com o Desktop e facilita Debug e visualização de ativos no Dispositivo.

No site da Adobe diz que funciona com Android e iOS mas eu só usei com iOS até agora. Você não deverá ter problemas com o Android.

O Desktop deve ser Windows ou MAC OS X. Eu só testei no MAC OS X.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta e desculpe a demora! Tentei adicionar o ip, hostname e não é concluído o processo de adicionar o pc no smartphone. Apresenta erro informando que não foi localizado. Ao tentar deixar o smartphone localizar algum pc em rede, também não localiza.

Answer (score 0):

O Google Chrome implementou uma nova tecnologia que permite fazer Debugging remoto por meio do navegador em qualquer elemento que utilize WebKit, por exemplo uma WebView em um App, como o Cordova utiliza ou o navegador.
Para isso é necessário possuir o Chrome 32 no computador e no dispositivo, um cabo usb e os drivers para usuários Windows.

Para ativar o Debugging remoto você deve ir em opções de desenvolver no Android (Configurações -> Programador na versão 4.4.2 do Android).
Depois você deve ativar a Depuração USB.

No computador acesse o endereço `about:inspect` no Google Chrome para ativar a funcionalidade.
O processo é simples e não deve causar problemas. Quando tudo estiver pronto conecte seu aparelho por meio de um cabo USB. Na primeira vez o aparelho ira pedir para aceitar uma chave RSA, feito isso você pode começar o debug remoto indo no menu do Google Chrome --> Ferramentas --> Inspecionar Dispositivos.